# Average - Map - Infinite number of points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, contest-math

I have a problem to solve in the context of the preparation of the PUTNAM competition. I am asked to find the average of a certain map of  $S \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ (domain $S$ is uncountable) into $\mathbb{R}$ ($T : S \to \mathbb{R}$ with $(x,y,z) \to T(x,y,z)$). Should I use the complete concept of integral to find the average of all $T (x, y, z)$, where $(x, y, z) \subset \mathbb{R^3}$, because I have an infinite number of points.

Here I don't want to mention the explicit map for reasons that I will myself resolve the matter.

Comment: Probably with Darboux Theorem (integrability)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your domain $S$ is countably infinite, you could use infinite summation to find the "average." No integral is needed.

However, there is no fully additive uniform distribution over a countably infinite set. So any "average" would need to be done with a weighting of the points. If no weight is given, implied, or obvious, we could say that there is no such thing as an "average" of the mapping.

If your domain $S$ is uncountable, then you would need an integral or something like it. There are multiple kinds of integral available, such as the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals, not to mention various measures. If the integral/measure of the image is finite, the average can be defined. I can think of some situations where the image has infinite size where an average could still be defined, but I would think that could get complicated.

This answer is somewhat vague, due to you not giving details about your mapping. I hope this helps.

---

If $S$ is uncountable, the basic way to use an integral to get the average of the mapping $T$ is

$$\overline T=\frac{\iiint_S T(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz}{\iiint_S\,dx\,dy\,dz}$$

This works if the denominator, $\iiint_S\,dx\,dy\,dz$, is finite and non-zero. If that integral is zero because $S$ has fewer than three dimensions, $S$ could be parameterized by one or two variables and a single or double integral used, and that may work. If the denominator is infinite, you may be able to get a meaningful average by using a sequence of bound sets $S_k$ for $k\in\Bbb N$ for which $S=\bigcup S_k$ and use the limit of the averages over $S_k$.

Does one of these meet your needs?

Comment: Here the domain is uncountable.

Comment: Are you able to develop a bit in the case where T(S) has a uncountable number of points?